# Windows 1903 and 1909 DNS Authentication fails

Tags: windows, server, dns

We have encountered a rather odd issue and hopefully someone here could shed some light.

We have two networks, we have rolled out windows 1903 to the Left network, and everything is fine and it all works.

On the right network we have prepared a 1903 image and a 1909 image consecutively,  neither of the two images can authenticate against DNS.

How do I know? The logs say so...
The build from MDT failed to find the server. IP's are DHCP allocated and IPCONFIG  /ALL says the network config is correct. And since all the 1809 machines work I can say its not IP config related. I have seen a few posts about this issue through various searches. But non have a cause or solution because people keep looking at network config. IT IS NOT network config.

On the DC/DNS server there are no logs of the issue, on the client there are a few logs about DNS referring to kerberos and authentication failures. These are scattered through out the eventviewer in different logs.

We have checked all the accounts concerned. The computer Account fails to be created because the Domain Controller is not available. Which is because if you try ping it its not found by fqdn.

The symptoms are fairly simple, you can ping external sites such as www.bing.com, dns resolve it and we get a reply, So our forwarders are working.
However when I try ping dc-01 or dc-01.mydomian.net I get "request could not find host"
In fact I get that on every internal fqdn.

nslookup - returns server as Unknown

So what is different between the two networks. We have a pretty equal mix of servers from 2012R2 upwards on both networks. I can't seem to figure out what we need to change in the right network to allow 1903 and 1909 to authenticate in DNS. its almost like some protected mode is enabled?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards
Chadley

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. It turns out you need to add the admx for 1903 and 1909.